# SAP Crystal Report refer to sum but not calculate

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a sum I want to basically copy the text but not calculate the formula.

**Sum formula:**

```
if next ({field}) > 0 then next ({field}) - {field2}
```

Formula works fine, I need to duplicate/copy the **Sum ##**, but I don't want the formula.

I've tried **Totext, CSTR, true/false** etc... everything copies the sum formula.

I just need something like "**sum**" and no formula.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
abs (if next ({field}) > 0 then next ({field}) - {field2})
```